# How do I read in data from a JSON file using dc.js?

Tags: javascript, json, dc.js

I want to read in data from a JSON file using dc.js, but I am fairly new to programming and I don't know how to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the following:

```
d3.json("filename", function(error, data) {
  //Insert code here
}
```